# JSON data format in NVD3 chart

Tags: javascript, json, nvd3.js

I have a chart template for a multi bar chart in NVD3 here: http://jsfiddle.net/hohenheim/6R7mu/5/

I have the following JSON data I want to display:

```
[{"date": 1396828800, "impressions": 49145385},
{"date": 1396915200, "impressions": 46704447},
{"date": 1397001600, "impressions": 47181000},
{"date": 1397088000, "impressions": 47337965},
{"date": 1397174400, "impressions": 51129266},
{"date": 1397260800, "impressions": 60547397},
{"date": 1397347200, "impressions": 62217077},
{"date": 1397433600, "impressions": 49145385},
{"date": 1397520000, "impressions": 46704447},
{"date": 1397606400, "impressions": 47181000},
{"date": 1397692800, "impressions": 47337965},
{"date": 1397779200, "impressions": 51129266},
{"date": 1397865600, "impressions": 60547397},
{"date": 1397952000, "impressions": 62217077}]
```

I'm looking to use JSON data I have (shown above and also commented out in the fiddle) but don't have any idea how to get it in the format that this NVD3 chart will accept. The chart is currently using sample data that is meaningless to me.

Is there a way to convert my data into something NVD3 will accept? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Does it have to be NVD3? Google Charts' data format might be simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data5 seems to have this format:

```
[
  {key: x, values: VALUES, vAxis: 1},
  {key: x, values: VALUES, vAxis: 1} // and maybe more for more colors
]
```

and VALUES seems to have this format:

```
[
  {x: 0, y: N},
  {x: 1, y: N},
  {x: 2, y: N} // and more for more on the X axis
]
```

So you have to rewrite your data to that format. Only it seems you don't have more sources. You have only 1 color. What makes `{"date": 1396828800, "impressions": 49145385}` one or the other? Is `date` the X axis?

Assuming the order of your data is correct, and it's only 1 source:

```
data5 = [{key: 'X', values: [], vAxis: 1}]
yourData.forEach(function(el, i) {
  data5[0].values.push({x: i, y: el.impressions});
     // ^ only 1 source/color
                        // ^ incremental X, starting at 0
});
```

You might have to adjust the x and y range somehow. (Maybe vAxis is one?)

Comment: My other source of data is a little more complicated and was planning on adding it after I figured this out - so for now only 1 color.

But yes, date is the x and impressions is the y. I managed a nice solution using the array.map property but essentially its the same as what you suggested.

Comment: Yes, `map()` would work, since the indexes are numerical. Smart. How's the result? Open source it!

Comment: Thanks, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/hohenheim/6R7mu/6/

Still need to figure out how to display/convert dates instead of milliseconds on the x-axis.

Comment: You could use Date: `d=new Date; d.setTime(num*1000);` (setTime takes ms, not s) and then use `getFullYear` and `getDate` and `getMonth+1`

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon their github page, and seems the above answer is correct.

https://github.com/novus/nvd3/wiki/Sample-chart-(your-first-nvd3-chart!)
The data format for charts is supposed to be:

```
[
    {
        key: "<Series name>",
        color: "<CSS color>",
        values: [
            {x: 0, y: 10},
            {x: 1, y: 20},
            {x: 2, y: 30}
            ....
        ]
    },
    {
        key: "<Series name>"
        ...
    }
]
```