# is there a more pythonic way to handle merging a list of tuples with a list into a dictionary?

Tags: python, flask

I am using Python3, I'm currently trying to refactor some code and this in particular looks a bit sloppy. Right now I have a standard for loop going though the list of tuples and pairing them with hard coded keys.

```
    values = [
        (1, 'test1', 15.5),
        (2, 'test2', 31.67),
        (3, 'item1', 16.5),
        (4, 'bike1', 15.5),
    ]

    keys = ['id', 'name', 'price']

    items = []

    for row in values:
        items.append({'id': row[0], 'name': row[1], 'price': row[2]})

    return items
```

Here is a similar article
[More efficient way to create JSON from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39842766/more-efficient-way-to-create-json-from-python)

However I'm having a hard time figuring how how to handle the fact my two sets of data are pretty different

```
    items = [row for row in result]
    columns = [key[0] for key in cursor.description]

    print([{key: val} for key, val in zip(columns, items)] )
```

I cam up with this, which could be condensed into one line theoretically. But since my data isn't 1 for 1 ( i.e. a list vs a list of tupels ) it gives me this...

```
[{'id': (1, 'bike2', 15.5)}, {'name': (2, 'test', 31.67)}, {'price': (3, 'bike3', 15.5)}]
```

`UPDATE`

Here was my final solution, thanks Martijn!

```
items = [dict(zip([key for key in keys], row)) for row in result]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there; you need to zip individual rows, not all rows at once:

```
[dict(columns, row) for row in result]
```

However, you can simply tell `sqlite` to produce dictionaries for each row, by setting the [`row_factory`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.row_factory):

```
def dict_factory(cursor, row):
    return {d[0]: col for d, col in zip(cursor.description, row)}

connection.row_factory = dict_factory
```

at which point you simply return the cursor results as a list:

```
return cursor.fetch_all()
```